# MySQL Update Query?

Tags: mysql

As my project gathers pace I have noticed that some users are inputting Aircraft Models incorrectly - (field is "model") for instance as -

737-8AS
737-8k3
757-222
etc

What I want to do via a query is to run through these and add a leading "B", for instance the above would be changed to:

B737-8AS
B737-8k3
B757-222

What I have in my daily update script is -

`/* Set Boeings */
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B707-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '707-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B717-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '717-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B727-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '727-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B737-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '737-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B747-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '747-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B757-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '757-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B767-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '767-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B777-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '777-%';
UPDATE`spotting`SET`model`='B787-%' WHERE`model`LIKE '787-%';`

This does edit the data to give the leading "B" but it then drops everything after the B737-

where "737-8AS/W" becomes "B737-" where it should be "B737-8AS/W"

I am guessing this is something simple I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

% is just a wild-card character; the update statement doesn't 'know' what the wildcard matched in the where clause. You'll want to include the actual current value in the update statement, something like:

```
UPDATE spotting SET model = CONCAT('B',model) WHERE model LIKE '707-%';
```

Answer (score 0):

It should just be `SET model='B-' + model`, I think. You need to add the new text to the existing value. The % does nothing in that context. And I think therefore you only need one update statement, because you're prepending the same thing to every row.

```
UPDATE spotting SET model = 'B-' + model WHERE model LIKE '7%';
```

Also you should consider adding some input validation to whatever form people are using to input this data, so the numbers are always in the correct format in future.

Comment: I am adding the input validation but as some data will come directly from "automatic radar systems" (e.g. data will be drawn in from other sources) it will still need some adjustments making.

Comment: That's fair enough, although you could potentially still do some up-front cleansing or filtering as part of the import process, however you're doing it. Anyway, does the altered query work? If so please remember to accept the answer - thanks :-)